# Determining the time complexity c++

Tags: c++, time-complexity, big-o

given the statements:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i = i * 2)
  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
```

how is this o(n) runtime?
I am pretty sure the first for loop runs in O(logn) but I am not sure how to interpret the second for loop.

Comment: how many times do you think the inner for loop runs when `i` is `n`, wouldn't it be `for(int j=0; j<n; j++)`?

Comment: Check this one out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63305948/has-this-snippet-olog2n-complexity

Comment: Suppose `n` is a power of 2 and count the iterations by hand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has this snippet O(log^2(n)) complexity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63305948/has-this-snippet-olog2n-complexity)

Answer (score 1):

For the start, I will assume that `n` is a potency of 2, plus 1 (so that `i` actually reaches it).
Given that, in the last iteration of the outer loop, we have `i = n`. For that value, the inner loop will iterate `n` times.
Now, the second last iteration of the outer loop had `i` being half that value. Thus, the inner loop had `i/2` iterations back then.
Putting the steps of each inner loop in reverse, we get the total amount of steps being

n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ...

This sum is equal to 2*n-1, **which is in Θ(n)**.

(If `n` is not a potency of 2, the last value of `i` is the last potency of 2 that is smaller than `n`, thus we still keep our complexity class.)